# overriding methods for a custom Filter Input Stream in java

Tags: java, overriding, inputstream, java-io

I have stumbled upon this problem:

So I have created a class for a custom filtered input stream and overridden the read() method.
I also need to override the read(byte[] b) method in a way that it uses the criteria that i had defined for the read() method but it does not do. I have tried many ways.

```
public class CustomInput extends FilterInputStream{

    protected CustomInput(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int y=super.read();
        if(y==65) {
            return 194;
        } else {
            return y;
        }
        
        
        
    }
    

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException{

    }

}
```

I do not know how to make each byte that the method reads whether it is a 65 and return a 194, and if it is not a 65 return whatever it reads just like I have defined in the read()  method.

Comment: You could solve this with a `for` or `while` loop, in which you call `read`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but I really wanted to have a separate method for it.

Comment: Is there a way I could make a separate method for it?
This would be so helpful.

Comment: What do you mean? You could define as much methods as you like.